# Does Google Analytics by MonsterInsights wordpress plugin insert tracking code automatically or does it just fetch the analytics data?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Here's what I did,

1. Installed [**Google Analytics by MonsterInsighs**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) plugin on WordPress
   site.
2. Authenticated and Connected the plugin to use corresponding Google
   Analytics Property

I have not manually inserted any tracking code on my site. I am under the impression that the tracking code insertion is (and should be) the task of MonsterInsights plugin. With that strong supposition, I cleared the cache on Site CDN and Site Server to check if the tracking code is inserted. The three verification methods I used are;

1. Verification through [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) Chrome Plugin
2. Verification through [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome Plugin
3. Manual Verification by Viewing Page Source

Ther are no errors in the plugin page. None of the methods have indicated the presence of tracking code. You can have a look yourself at https://techmars.org

**PS:** All of these activities are very recent i.e. It has just been an hour. Does it usually take some waiting? I haven't encountered such a prerequisite anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonsterInsights automatically adds the tracking script. It appears to have done so on your site. The only time it would require waiting is if you were to use some sort of page caching that needs to clear for new frontend output tags to show.

Comment: I checked once again. At first, I couldn't find the tracking script. And I do use page caching on the site. Once again I cleared it but no use. So I decided to _clear the browser cache as well and surprisingly the tracking script appeared._ It was surprising because it should not have to do anything with the browser cache. On further investigation, I found that I was signed-in to the back-end all this while and **MonsterInsights has a default configuration which avoids tracking of logged-in users.** Technically, it can be termed as some sort of credentials caching I suppose. Thanks.